# ListView Item select in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I want to select item in a ListView upon clicking. I also want to know what I clicked. 
I work on winforms with c#.I also want to know How I can clicking the all row?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just handle the `Click` event on the list and use the `ListView.SelectedItems` property to get what items are selected:

```
private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstSelectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

Comment: if I click twice on the same item it will dispatch the event twice when it should not because the selection didn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

u can use MouseEventArgs  and get the mouse location check if it exists inside the selected item bound , that means the click was made on the selected item .

**EDIT :** 
example :

```
    private void myList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myList.SelectedItems.Count  >= 1)
        {
            ListViewItem item = myList.SelectedItems[0];

            //here i check for the Mouse pointer location on click if its contained 
            // in the actual selected item's bounds or not .
            // cuz i ran into a problem with the ui once because of that ..
            if (item.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Double Clicked on :"+item.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

also if you use xaml for window then you must add MouseUp="listView1_Click" attribute to ListView tag